# How to determine the height cover by the content assuming container height is fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know is there any way in JavaScript to determine height of the content so that I can reset the height of container.

for example I have a div which have height 200px. div have content which cover less height (assuming 40px). How can I get the height if I add more content in it.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Please, make clear if you're using a library (jQuery, MooTools…) or not. This changes the potential answers a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height to an empty string, add your new content, and measure the offsetHeight of the element.  Of course if you don't want to see it flash briefly, you can do it in a copy of the element with visibility set to hidden.  If you are near the right or bottom edges of the browser window, it may try to force the element to fit on screen, if you don't want this, absolutely position the element and give it negative top and left coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the content height only, then you can add another div inside, and if you'r using jQuery:

```
var innerDiv = $('#main .inner').height() + 'px';
```

You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/

http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/equal-height-columns.html

If you want to google yourself, try: "Equal height column jquery"